# Pythonic way of handling multiple possible file locations? (Without using nested trys)

Tags: python, exception

I have a Python script that needs to look for a certain file.

I could use os.path.isafile(), but I've heard that's bad Python, so I'm trying to catch the exception instead.

However, there's two locations I could possibly look for the file. I could use nested trys to handle this:

```
try:
    keyfile = 'location1'
    try_to_connect(keyfile)
except IOError:
    try:
        keyfile = 'location2'
        try_to_connect(keyfile)
    except:
        logger.error('Keyfile not found at either location1 or location2')
```

Or I could just put a pass in the first except block, and then have another one just below:

```
try:
    keyfile = 'location1'
    try_to_connect(keyfile)
except IOError:
    pass
try:
    keyfile = 'location2'
    try_to_connect(keyfile)
except:
    logger.error('Keyfile not found at either location1 or location2')
```

However, is there a more Pythonic way to handle the above situation?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Why don't you write a loop? -1 for not knowing the concept of a loop

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question asking for a more pythonic method of doing so.  I don't really think you can ding him for not thinking of looping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for location in locations:
    try:
        try_to_connect(location)
        break
    except IOError:
        continue
else:
    # this else is optional
    # executes some code if none of the locations is valid
    # for example raise an Error as suggested @eumiro
```

Also you can add an `else` clause to the for loop; that is some code is executed only if the loop terminates through exhaustion (none of the locations is valid).

Comment: I would add `else:` to the `for` block with error message that none of the locations matched.

Comment: +1. Also, you probably want to wrap this up in a function `try_to_connect_one_of(locations)` (although maybe with a better name…).